# Cannot read JSON value from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm on a react-native project where I'm querying firebase to get some data from Firebase realtime database. However I receive my required output by below code.

```
getData = (email) => {
let usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
usersRef.orderByChild('emailAddress').equalTo(email).on("value", (snapshot) => {
  let data  = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.emailAddress);
});
```

}

But unexpectedly I get the output for second log as `undefined`.

[image: Firebase Return view in Chrome Inspect]

**Problem**

I cannot read the value of `emailAddress`. I don't understand why. 
Below is my database structure.

[image: DB structure]

Comment: Can you post your JSON that you consoled?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing foreEach function since it returns proto as well.

```
getData = (email) => {
  let usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
  usersRef.orderByChild('emailAddress').equalTo(email).on("value", (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      console.log(snap.val().emailAddress);
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: That is indeed the correct approach. When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So when you `on("value"`, the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result and you need to `snapshot.forEach()` to access each result.